# Kafka Streams: Processor sometimes processes same messages upon application restart

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

In my Java application I have a Kafka Processor.

My process method looks like this:

```
@Override
public void process(String key, String value) {
    System.out.println("In the process method, the offset is: " + context.offset());
    //Some more code
}
```

where context is the ProcessorContext from the init method.

I start the application and this is logged:

```
In the process method, the offset is: 1203
In the process method, the offset is: 1204
```

Then I start the application again, and I get the same messages. After a couple of application restarts (or after some time, I can't find a pattern), the process method stops getting called and I no longer get these messages on application start.

Any idea why these messages are sometimes being processed multiple times?

My Streams Config has the following properties:

```
props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "someId");
props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.StringSerde.class.getName());
props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.StringSerde.class.getName());
props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_TIMESTAMP_EXTRACTOR_CLASS_CONFIG, WallclockTimestampExtractor.class.getName());
props.put(StreamsConfig.NUM_STREAM_THREADS_CONFIG, 10);
props.put(StreamsConfig.STATE_DIR_CONFIG, "somedir");
```

**EDIT**

The code snippet below shows how I create the KafkaStreams:

```
public class KafkaStreamsProcessorBean implements SmartLifecycle {
    @Override
    public synchronized void start() {
        final KStreamBuilder builder = new KStreamBuilder();

        final KStream<String, String> debeziumStream = builder.stream("debezium.topic");
        debeziumStream.process(() -> debeziumProcessor);

        kafkaStreams = new KafkaStreams(builder, streamsConfig);
        kafkaStreams.start();
    }
}
```

Here streamsConfig is the configuration with the properties I have shown and debeziumProcessor is the Kafka Processor from the first code snippet.

Comment: Depending on the configuration at some point "old" messages gets deleted from a topic. Therefore you can't read them anymore when you read the messages from a topic.

Comment: Not reading them is exactly what I want. If I understand correctly, after the processor reads a message, the offset should iterate.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full source code as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default Kafka Streams processing guarantee is *At least once*. That means that messages can be reprocessed.

In your case even if you will set `StreamsConfig.PROCESSING_GUARANTEE_CONFIG` to `StreamsConfig.EXACTLY_ONCE` you could see same logs (with same offset info) after restart.

Processing guarantee is regarding writing an **offset** and the **result** to the topic in one transaction. 
It doesn't mean that message can't be *process* several time (call Processor::process(...) several time with same key and value).

Following scenario is possible:

- Message was read.
- `Processor::process(...)` was called.
- Application finished without writing an offset.
- After restart application will read same message and `Processor::process(...)` for same key and value will be called

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am not very experienced in distributed systems but I need the message to be sent exactly once. I thought StreamsConfig.EXACTLY_ONCE was exactly what I needed, however when I add it to the SteamsConfig, I never receive any message in the process method.

The messages are still being sent, I can see the using the console consumer. 
Do you have any idea why this could be happening?

Comment: @LyubomirPapazov, Could you add your code snipped of building your topology?

Comment: I have updated the question with the relevant information about how the KafkaStreams object is created.

Comment: @LyubomirPapazov, please make sure, that you have not change anything else, setting EXACTLY_ONCE property  should not cause not reading any messages

Comment: You also need to distinguish the error case and the normal processing case. For the original example, you should call `KafkaStreams#close()` if you stop your application -- this ensure the you won't process messages twice on regular shutdown. For the error case though, it would not prevent duplicates---to guard against the error case, you would need to enable exactly-once as described in this answer.